# Converting web app to ASP.NET MVC 3 - how to enable Razor views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, .net-4.0

I'm trying to convert existing asp.net application to MVC using [this](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html) link.

When adding views I have an option to add razor or an aspx view types. When using aspx type ( `<%: ViewBag.Message %>` ) everything works fine but if I try to use razor type ( `@ViewBag.Message` ) I get an error

```
CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
```

Visual Studios intellisense recognizes ViewBag class but runtime doesn't. (I'm using visual stuido dev server not local IIS).

I searched around the site for this message and everything I found suggested to update web.config (which I did) or run the Mvc3AppConverter, and neither of those helped me.

**EDIT**: My web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ShowLanguageReload" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Also it includes ,  and some additional keys in the appSettings, but I removed those as I believe they are not relevant to my question.

**EDIT #2** I also have a web.config in `Views\Shared` folder it looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the links, I read through them, the first one is very similar to the one I linked there are just a slight differences in the global.asax file, but those changes didn't help me. And for the second, I'm not trying to mix master pages (yet). It might be helpful in future but not for now.

Comment: Did you change web.config file in Views folder as well? You should...

Comment: Yes of couse, I'll update my question to include that config too.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik You're right, the problem was config in the Views folder. When I copied the config from Views\Shared into Views it worked. Could you please post an answer with this and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Two Scott Hanselman links

These two may help:

1. [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)
2. [Mixing Razor Views and WebForms Master Pages with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)

### Configuration

Don't forget that changing root folder's `web.config` isn't enough. You also need to have appropriate `web.config` file in the Views folder that configures Razor.

### Suggestion

As it seems you have too many things in your `Views\web.config`. I would take the barebones `web.config` file provided by the MVC VS project template because you're configuring things that don't need configuration here like `appSettings` etc.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these references,

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />        
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: @Yasser: And just FYI: Adding system.web/pages/namespaces is related to webforms engine and not razor. Just so you know... ;)